# UIButton as subview to UITextfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a subview: `UITextfield` that is being repositioned when an orientation change occurs. I would like ti add a `UIButton` to this subview so that the button will reposition with the `UITextField`.

This is easy to do, but for the button to work I need to set the `UITextField` to be `userInteractionEnabled`. The problem is that I need it not to be userInteractionEnabled.

Anyone know of a good solution for this?

Comment: can you please explain clearly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to create a UIView (a container view) then add the textfield and button to that view.  Then add this container view to your main view and reposition the container view as necessary.  Then the textfield and button will follow...